# Hierarchy of Topologies

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking over some questions, studying for my topology midterm tomorrow and I've come across a question I'm unsure about:

Show that the $T_1$-topology on the real line is coarser than the canonical topology.

My rough work for this question is that since the $T_1$ topology contains elements that are cofinite sets, we can always find a union of open intervals in the canonical topology that contains any element in the $T_1$ topology. However, the canonical topology contains open intervals with finite elements contained in it.

Thus we can consider the elements of $T_1$ topology as a "sub base" for the elements in the canonical topology since the finite intersection of elements in $T_1$ topology generate the canonical topology.

Edit:I use quotations around sub base since I'm unsure of the proper terminology

Thanks for looking over this and I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: What is the $T_1$ topology? The coarsest topology making the space $T_1$?

Comment: it is the collection of cofinite sets

Comment: It is coarser that the usual topology, as each finite set is closed.

Comment: I agree and understand, but fail to see the connection as to why this shows that this property makes the T1 topology coarser. Can you elaborate a litle more?

Comment: Just to be clear: in order to show a topology $T$ is coarser than a topology $T'$, one only needs to exhibit an open set in $T'$ which does not belong to $T$.

Comment: So take, for example, a bounded open interval.

Comment: Of course! The open interval (0,1) is not contained in the T1 topology since it is not a complement of a finite set. Thank you, I recall discussing this in lecture now. Thank you to both of you!

Comment: In the $T_1$ topology the closed sets are the finite sets. A singleton $\{x\}$ is also closed in the Euclidean topology. But a finite set is just a union of finitely man singletons, so it must be closed in the Euclidean topology. This argument can actually be carried out in any topology where points are closed, so it shows that the cofinite topology is the coarsest topology making a space $T_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response Stefan.